# How to append a nested, looped object to a WHERE Statement in Powershell

Tags: sql, powershell

Basically I'm trying to take 5 SQL Queries, and run them against a list of hundreds of Object IDs, and then export the results across 5 Query named tabs inside an XLSX named after each Object ID.  I'm so close but I just don't know how to add those Object IDs into each Query's WHERE clause.  I get data if I break the loop and include $obj, and don't get data otherwise.

```
$SQLServer = "Servername"
    $SQLDBName = "Database"
    $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; Integrated Security = True"  #; User ID = $uid; Password = $pwd;
    $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
 
 
   $SQL_Object_IDs = get-content "C:\PS\INPUT\Obj_IDs.txt"   
 
    $SQL_QUERY1 = 
    "Select [r_object_id] as 'Object ID'
    From [Database].[dbo].[table1]
    Where blah blah blah = ''"
    #$SQL_QUERY2 = Query2.SQL
    #$SQL_QUERY3 = Query3.SQL
    #$SQL_QUERY4 = Query4.SQL
    #$SQL_QUERY5 = Query5.SQL
 
    $SqlQueries = $SQL_QUERY1, =#,$SQL_QUERY2,$SQL_QUERY3,$SQL_QUERY4,$SQL_QUERY5
 
    $ExcelOutputPath = "C:\PS\OUTPUT\COLLATED_OBJ_IDs\"          
    $OutputExcelTabNames= "Obj_ID_Type1","Obj_ID_Type2","Obj_ID_Type3","Obj_ID_Type4","Obj_ID_Type5"          
    ForEach ($obj in $SQL_Object_IDs)
    {
   
            $SheetNo = 0
        
              ForEach ($SqlQuery in $SqlQueries)
              {
         
                    $DestinationPath = $ExcelOutputPath  + "\"+ $obj+".xlsx"
                    $SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
                    $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
                    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
                    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
                    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
                    $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
 
                    $DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-Excel -Path $DestinationPath -AutoSize -AutoFilter  -BoldTopRow -ClearSheet -WorksheetName $OutputExcelTabNames[$SheetNo]
                
                    $SheetNo += 1
 
              }
```

Comment: I feel like I'm grossly overthinking this and I simply need to add some iteration of $_.obj into the Queries themselves, but so far every version has resulted in a broken loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The safest way to pass arguments to a T-SQL query is by declaring and binding [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataadapter-parameters):

```
$SQL_QUERY1 = 
"Select [r_object_id] as 'Object ID'
From [Database].[dbo].[table1]
Where columnName = @columnValue"

# ...

foreach($obj in $SQL_Object_IDs) {

    $sheetNo = 0

    foreach($SqlQuery in $SQLQueries) {
        $DestinationPath = $ExcelOutputPath  + "\"+ $obj +".xlsx"
        $SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
        $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection

        # clear any parameters from previous iterations
        $SqlCmd.Parameters.Clear()

        # bind appropriate value to parameter
        #SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue('@columnValue', $obj)

        $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
        $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
        $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
        $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
 
        $DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-Excel -Path $DestinationPath -AutoSize -AutoFilter  -BoldTopRow -ClearSheet -WorksheetName $OutputExcelTabNames[$SheetNo]
    }
}
```

The call to `$SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue('@columnValue', $obj)` will replace the `@columnValue` placeholder in the query text with value stored in `$obj`.

If the Object ID values are *numerical*, then you'll want to convert `$obj` to `[int]` before binding the value:

```
# bind appropriate value to parameter
#SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue('@columnValue', [int]$obj)
```

Comment: Would that still be the case if I wanted to  call queries from files instead of baked fully into the script?

Comment: This is assuming you're reading the ID values from the file (just like you're already doing), yes - but it'll work either way.

Comment: Oh I gotcha, bake @columnValue into each query.SQL's WHERE clause.

Comment: Is there anyway to suppress the CompareInfo / Schema info blurb per query per OBJ ID?